# How can I ensure that my model named View will be called instead of laravel's View

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a model named 'View' but laravel also has View object (the "V" in the MVC). I will be calling my model 'View' from different areas of my application. How can I make sure that it's not referring to laravel's View?

Answer (score 1):

*Extending @RonaldPK 's answer a little bit.*

You have your `App\View` and Laravel has `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`

use your App\View as ViewModel instead of View. That should do it.

`Use App\View as ViewModel;`

A better option: using ViewInterface and referencing it to your model. This will help you get rid of lots of problems at once.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php): "a way of encapsulating items" in order to prevent name collisions.